# DataGridView not displaying data while DataSet contains the data

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, dataadapter

In the following code, I can see that my `DataSet` is already filled with data but my `DataGridView` displays nothing:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
try
{
    ds = new DataSet("Downloads");
    using (IDbConnection conn = dataFactory.GetDbConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = Common.Conf.ConnectionString;
        da = dataFactory.GetDbDataAdapter();
        IDbCommand cmd = dataFactory.GetDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;                       
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
    }
    dgv.DataSource = ds;                
    dgv.DataMember = "Downloads";
    if (dgv.Rows == null || dgv.Rows.Count == 0)
        lblDownloads.Text = "No download history found";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and check your `da` and `ds` have data?

Comment: @SonerGönül my `ds` has the data and my `da` retrieves the correct `IDbDataAdapter` from my factory.

Comment: And if you replace "dgv.DataSource = ds;" by "dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]" ?

Comment: @Marc still nothing. :(

Comment: Are you sure your full code is not clearing or reinstanciating your dataset somewhere after executing this statement ?

Comment: @Marc Oh I am sorry. I replaced your `dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]` in the wrong class. Now it is working. So thank you. But it is strange. I am running a very similar code in another class and I set my `DataGridView`'s DataSource to my `ds`. Can you somehow explain it briefly in an answer so I accept it as correct?

Comment: A dataset is made to contains several datatables. Therefore, when you're binding a dataset to a datagridview you need to specify which table of your dataset has to be displayed. To do this there is 2 solutions: 1. `datagriview.DataSource = DataSet.Tables["MyTable"];` 2. `datagridview.DataSource = DataSet;` `datagridview.DisplayMember = "MyTable";` In your case, "Downloads" is the name of your dataset but not of your datatable. If you wanted to name your datatable "Downloads" use `da.Fill(ds, "Downloads");`